# Objective C: Infinite getter method loop after converting to ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)someArray{ // line 1
    if(self.someArray == nil){ // line 2
        self.someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }  
    return self.someArray;
}
```

I had this in non-ARC, and it works fine: If `self.someArray` in line 2 is `nil`, then go ahead and instantiate it.

However, after I switched to ARC, when it gets to line 2, it goes back to line 1, and the loop continues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper form is

```
@synthesize someArray = _someArray;
- (NSMutableArray *)someArray {
    if (!_someArray) {
        _someArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _someArray;
}
```

Comment: You can leave out the @sythesize line, by default the variable name will have a preceding underscore and you could use the rest of the code as-is.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how this worked before. The problem has nothing to do with ARC.

Answer (score 5):

self.someArray calls the getter, hence the infinite loop. use _someArray within that method instead (assuming you're using the automatic ivar provided by the property. Otherwise, use whatever your backing variable is).

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you are calling the accessor method inside the accessor. But if every accessor calls itself, you'll never break this cycle.

Use the auto synthesized property to avoid this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)someArray{ // line 1
    if(_someArray == nil){ // line 2
        _someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }  
    return _someArray;
}
```